# https Docker for Production on VPS

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, docker, vps

Just a simple question about using Docker for production.

If we have a VPS (ex: linux OS) and installed a Docker containing a java application (ex: Spring boot).
What could be the best choice to expose https:
 1. Apache on vps with reverse proxy
 2. Java app in https directly
 3. Docker exposing https

the point 1 could be a good choice but Docker still expose behind a http localhost .

What do you think ?

Comment: 2 - May be the simplest: single container doing everything

Comment: 1 - once you need to scale up and add more instances of your app

Comment: 3 - not sure what you mean by that…